# Helm alt-tab-like function

Tags: buffers, helm

I essentially want to bring up the helm buffers list and hit `RET`. This goes to the previous buffer in an alt-tab-like manner.

Thought this would do the trick but stops short of actually exiting the minibuffer:

```
(defun helm-alt-tab ()
  "Acts as a buffer alt-tab using helm."
  (interactive)
  (helm-buffers-list)
  (helm-maybe-exit-minibuffer))
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly you want to achieve? Spawning a helm interface is one thing, you hitting `RET` however is unclear (since `RET` should already exit helm just fine). `helm-buffers-list` already gives me the last buffer as preselected choice, so you get that, too. What exactly is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: @wasamasa I'd like to store that action sequence in a function so I can bind it to a key such that I reduce my keystrokes.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to involve helm in that if you're not going to use its facilities and will just get a brief flash.

Comment: IMHO it's useful to have the short version that just switches and the long version that preselects the alternate but lets you see the full list.  I have the two different versions bound to different keys, I find them both indispensable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(defun my-switch-to-last-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer nil))
```

No need to involve helm to have a command for switching to the last buffer interactively at all.

Comment: Instead of `(switch-to-buffer nil)` I use `(switch-to-buffer (other-buffer (current-buffer))))` because the latter is better about excluding some buffers (I forget the details, but it annoyed me a while back).

Answer (score 0):

I use helm like so, to do what you describe.  Source unknown, but I didn't write it originally :)

```
(defun helm-buffers-list ()
  "Preconfigured `helm' to list buffers."
  (interactive)
  (helm :sources '(helm-source-buffers-list
                   helm-source-ido-virtual-buffers
                   helm-source-buffer-not-found)
        :buffer "*helm buffers*"
        :keymap helm-buffer-map
        :truncate-lines t
        :preselect (buffer-name (other-buffer (current-buffer) 1))))
```